# smartgwt listgrid set cursor to hand over an icon field

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I've been working on this problem for quite a while but have not been able to solve it.
I have a listgrid with a field type icon.  I would like to change the cursor to "hand" over the icon.

I've been searching the web and saw that a couple of solutions existed.
One of them is using `addCellOverHandler` for the list grid.  But I don't understand how you can change the cursor for the specified field of the listgrid.

```
this.addCellOverHandler(new CellOverHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onCellOver(CellOverEvent event) {
    // not able to get the field and setCursor()        
    }
});
```

My field in the listgrid is defined as:

```
ListGridField iconField = new ListGridField("icon");
iconField.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
iconField.setType(ListGridFieldType.ICON);
iconField.setIcon("icons/icon.gif");
```

Like someone pointed out on the forum, a `setCursor()` method exist for the listgrid, but not for the field only...

If anybody has a clue...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more (a lot more...) googling, I found this:

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=15748

The thing is to Override the `getCellStyle` method in the listgrid.
Here is the code I use:

```
@Override
protected String getCellStyle(ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum) {
    if (colNum==6){
        return "EC_pointer";
    }
    return super.getCellStyle(record, rowNum, colNum);
}
```

and in my CSS file:

```
.EC_pointer { 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

The major fallout is that you have to know in advance the column number of the field.

Comment: Easiest and simplest way to add, if modifying the the existing grid. Otherwise the next answer is the better approach or the modern approach.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment and adding information from [here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=5642) I tested the following code which works with SmartGwt2.4 under Firefox 5.0.

```
demandesGrid.setCanHover(true);
demandesGrid.setShowHover(false);
demandesGrid.addCellHoverHandler(new CellHoverHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onCellHover(CellHoverEvent event) {
        if (event.getColNum() == demandesGrid.getFieldNum("icon")) {
        //  SC.say(demandesGrid.getChildren()[3].toString());
            demandesGrid.getChildren()[3].setCursor(Cursor.POINTER);
        } else {
            demandesGrid.getChildren()[3].setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know if the index of the `ListGridBody` is constant; I found it with the `SC.say` line.

Comment: I had seen that post on the forum without being able to apply this solution.  Your solution works but there are two problems with it.  The first is that if you have to specified the third children of the grid, I have to specify the second.  I don't know why... The second thing is the behavior of the cursor which does turns to pointer type over my icon field but takes a little time to turns back to normal after you leave the field.  I will edit my solution which I find, works better.  Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped a lot !!

Comment: For the child index it's normal, it depends of the setup of the listgrid some elements could be there or not. For the delay time I've seen that too but didn't check in production mode to see if it was the same. Anyway your css style method is better.

Comment: There is one thing that is not perfect in my method, as well as yours.  The cursor changes over the whole field and not just over the icon in the field.  So if you size your field just large enough to fit the icon, that's fine.  If you want a larger field, it is not very pretty to see your cursor become a pointer in the middle of nowhere...

Comment: Currently the ListGrid has a .getBody() method, which gives you exactly that child what is needed to set the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
grid.addCellOverHandler(new CellOverHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onCellOver(CellOverEvent event) {
    //cellOver event to get field and refresh the cell
    //grid.refreshCell(i, j);
  }
});
```

Comment: if(event.getColNum()== yourGrid.getFieldNum("icon")) but I don't know if you can set the cursor after that.

Comment: @Hardik Mishra:  I don't want to change the value of the field in the grid, just want the cursor to appear as a hand when above the icon.

Comment: @Alain BUFERNE: I had tried the same approach but I'm also stuck when it comes to changing the cursor...

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is fully demonstrated [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_cell_widgets) (take a look at how "comments/stats" field is being initialized).

In short, u have to extend ListGrid and override createRecordComponent method. In this method you can make any custom component you like and it will be show in grid cell.

Also ListGrid should be initialized with:

```
listGrid.setShowRecordComponents(true);
listGrid.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);
```